# How to implement process partitioning on non-integer keys without CRC32?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, partitioning

I'm working on PostgreSQL with a Ruby client and I want to partition a table with SHA-1 hash ids like

```
                    id                    
------------------------------------------
 fe935b318f6976afdec83fa7339ff2069b0bc0c3
 d67948e38a645fd5ffdde6dab4dc627b2b19d1b1
 0d304f5134b0a46c2248a34c3e9c50ad2b547fdf
```

[Process partitioning](http://miyagijournal.com/articles/8-process-partitioning-in-distributed-systems) is where you partition a dataset into N parts and assign each to one of N processes. If you have **integer** keys in a RDBMS, it is simple:

```
select * from items_to_be_processed where MOD(id, N) = ASSIGNED_PARTITION
```

[Ryan Smith](https://twitter.com/ryandotsmith) suggests that if you have string keys, you can use CRC32 on them to get the integer and then the modulus - but, assuming your keys are mostly evenly distributed (like I think it would be with SHA-1 hashes), would this be easier? For `N = 4`, like:

```
select * from items_to_be_processed where id < ASSIGNED_PARTITION_1
select * from items_to_be_processed where id < ASSIGNED_PARTITION_2 and id >= ASSIGNED_PARTITION_1
select * from items_to_be_processed where id < ASSIGNED_PARTITION_3 and id >= ASSIGNED_PARTITION_2
select * from items_to_be_processed where id >= ASSIGNED_PARTITION_4
```

so maybe if `N = 2`, then

```
select * from items_to_be_processed where id < '8888888888888888888888888888888888888888'   <- process 1
select * from items_to_be_processed where id >= '8888888888888888888888888888888888888888'  <- process 2
```

Given N, how do I calculate the partition points (`8888888888888888888888888888888888888888` dividing `ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` in half, which maybe I didn't even calculate correctly)? Should I do it in SQL (Postgres) or in the Ruby client making the call?

PS. Inspired by the [random attribute idea](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/) from the MongoDB cookbook.

**Update**

`888...` above was't calculated correctly - here's a way to do it in Ruby, thanks to Carl Norum's answer for bringing me closer:

```
>> 'f'*40
=> "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
>> a = 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
=> 1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542975
>> b = a / 2
=> 730750818665451459101842416358141509827966271487
>> '%x' % b
=> "7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
>> '%x' % (b + 1)
=> "8000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: A simpler approach would be to consider the first `M` characters of `id` which would apparently be a number expressed in  hexadecimal. Choose `M` depending on the number of partitions you need, given they'd be limited to `16^M`, a number that quickly gets huge. Then use directly the substring in `mod(number_from_substring, N)` to obtain the partition number.

Comment: You could store the id as binary (bytea) with about half the size of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the first *n* characters of the hash depending on how many partitions. If up to 16 then only the first character:

```
select *
from items_to_be_processed
where left(id, 1) < '4'

select *
from items_to_be_processed
where left(id, 1) between '4' and '7'
```

There is no need for a conversion to integer.

Then you can have an index on just the *n* left characters to make it small and fast:

```
create index index_name on items_to_be_processed (left(id, 1))
```

---

It is necessary to have the `left()` expression in the `where` clause to make the planner use the proposed small index contrarily to the comments to this answer. This is how I tested in 9.2:

```
create table itbp (id char(32));

insert into itbp
select md5(a::text)
from generate_series(1, 100000) s(a)
;
```

I used md5 in instead of sha1 just to create a simpler test as there is no sha1 function in the default install of postgresql.

```
create index itbp_left_1_id_index on itbp (left(id, 1));

analyze itbp;
```

I did not forget to analyze before testing. Now both the explains:

```
explain select *
from itbp
where left(id, 1) between '4' and '7'
;
                                             QUERY PLAN                                              
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on itbp  (cost=529.17..1979.74 rows=24663 width=33)
   Recheck Cond: (("left"((id)::text, 1) >= '4'::text) AND ("left"((id)::text, 1) <= '7'::text))
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on itbp_left_1_id_index  (cost=0.00..523.00 rows=24663 width=0)
         Index Cond: (("left"((id)::text, 1) >= '4'::text) AND ("left"((id)::text, 1) <= '7'::text))

explain select *
from itbp
where id >= '4' and id < '8'
;
                         QUERY PLAN                         
------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on itbp  (cost=0.00..2334.00 rows=24784 width=33)
   Filter: ((id >= '4'::bpchar) AND (id < '8'::bpchar))
```

Comment: @Phrogz Would the planner use the small index I proposed if the `left` expression were not in the `where` clause? Is it that smart? I don't have the time to test it now.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Ah, an excellent point on performance. I don't fully understand the output of the query plans, but I'll trust that what you say is true. I'll remove my incorrect comments from your answer now. :)

Answer (score 2):

That's not calculated correctly.  Your example is something like taking the base 10 number `9999` and saying that dividing it by `2` yields `5555`.  Rather:

```
0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Is one less than:

```
0x10000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Dividing that number into ranges is easy.  For your N=2 example, half of the keys are less than:

```
0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And half are greater than or equal.  For N=4, it's similar:

```
ASSIGNED_PARTITION_1 = 0x4000000000000000000000000000000000000000
ASSIGNED_PARTITION_2 = 0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000
ASSIGNED_PARTITION_3 = 0xc000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you try the partitioning with smaller numbers (like ones you can easily write in base 10), you'll see what's going on.

I'm not sure how the comparisons are going to work out for you - those are *big* numbers.  I'm not a ruby or SQL expert, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to do is to convert the id into an integer for partitioning purposes.  Here is a simple way to do that, assuming that the id values are distributed uniformly, you could use the first two digits to get a value from 0 to 255:

```
select substring(t.id, 1, 2)::bit(8)::int as IntHash,
       t.*
from t
```

You can then define your ranges using modular arithmetic, such as:

```
select (substring(t.id, 1, 2)::bit(8)::int)%8 as WhichOfEightPartitions
from t
```

This is assuming that the hash id is stored as a string.

The basic idea for this came from this [post](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Hex-to-Dec-Conversion-td3218223.html), in the response by "tom lane".  This is, apparently, undocumented behavior, but it does work on SQLFiddle.